# Ist "verbrennen" im folgenden Kontext frequentativ - dadurch, dass es vielen passiert? Aktionsart von Partizipien

Tags: meaning-in-context

Es geht um die Adjektive "verbrennend" und "verbrannt".

Der Post ist angelehnt an den [Beitrag zu "Fleischessenden"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74561/fleischessende-in-german-news-meat-eating-people-nominalised-participle-1https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74561/fleischessende-in-german-news-meat-eating-people-nominalised-participle-1) - baut jedoch darauf auf.

Der Kontext ist ein fiktiver Nachrichtenbeitrag:

> Der Tod durch das Feuer ist eine Tragödie. Wir tun unser Bestes, um die Anzahl Verbrennender geringzuhalten.

Nun gibt es das Argument: Es geht hier nicht um ausschließlich *momentan Verbrennende*, sondern ebenso um Menschen, welche in der Vergangenheit *am Verbrennen waren* und solche, die in der Zukunft *am Verbrennen sein werden*.
Das rechtfertige eine frequentative Bedeutung des Verbs dadurch, dass viele einzelne Geschehenisse über die Zeit zusammengezählt werden können.

Dem entgegne ich aber, dass es Unfug ist. Das Verb bezieht sich auf eine Gruppe, für die das Attribut "verbrennend" jeweils - unabhängig der anderen - wahr ist.
Dementsprechend deuten wir es so:

1. Es geht um Menschen, die wiederholt verbrennen.  (Unfug)
2. Es geht um Menschen, die gerade am Verbrennen sind.  (Möglich)

Die Nutzung würde also nur gerechtfertigt sein - so meine Meinung - wenn es zuträfe, dass sich aus der jeweiligen einmaligen Erlebnisse der Menschen, die die Gruppe der "Verbrennenden" ausmachen, eine im Großen und Ganzen frequentative Bedeutung des Verbes herbeiwünschen lassen würde.

Desweiteren:
Die Aktionsart des Partizip 1 als Attribut ist imperfektiv. Eine Verbindung mit dem Tod durch das Brennen lässt sich also hiermit gar nicht zwingend in Verbindung bringen - denn verbrannt sein muss nicht zwingend jemand.

Aufgrund dieser Argumente finde ich den fiktiven Beitrag als falsch formuliert. Was sagt ihr dazu?

Answer (score 2):

Das Partizip ist hier unbegründet. Nehmen wir an, das wäre ein Motivationssatz der Feuerwehr, dann würde sie von *Brandopfern* statt von *Verbrennenden* schreiben (weil *Verbrennen* nicht das einzige ist, was die Feuerwehr verhindern möchte, aber auch aus vielen anderen Gründen). Nimmt man ein Partizip, dann möchte man etwas was damit sagen - in den meisten Fällen entweder *Gleichzeitigkeit* oder *Regelmäßigkeit*. Beides scheint hier nicht die Absicht zu sein. *Verbrennen* ist final, zeitlich sehr begrenzt und eine Gleichzeitigkeit nicht sichtbar. Nimmt man ein anderes Verb, kommt einem die grammatische Konstruktion plötzlich nicht mehr ganz so sinnlos vor:

> Der Priester hatte großen Erfolg dabei, die Anzahl der Betenden in seiner Kirche zu erhöhen

Die Verwendung des Partizips ist hier begründet: Der Satz möchte ausdrücken, dass Leute regelmäßig und wiederholt in die Kirche kommen, um dort über einen längeren Zeitraum hinweg zu beten. (Alles Dinge, die man beim *Verbrennen* nicht machen kann). In deinem Beispiel widerspricht also die Semantik dem verwendeten grammatischen Stilmittel.